# Python - Pattern prediction using LSTM Recurrent Neural Networks with Keras

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am dealing with pattern prediction from a formatted [CSV dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vO62n7GolfvCOHLkPEmc1VLwrV6iPc5n) with three columns (time_stamp, X and Y - where Y is the actual value). I wanted to predict the value of X from Y based on time index from past values and here is how I approached the problem with LSTM Recurrent Neural Networks in Python with [Keras](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.0.4/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.random.seed(7)

df = pd.read_csv('test32_C_data.csv')
n_features=100

values = df.values

for i in range(0,n_features):
    df['X_t'+str(i)] = df['X'].shift(i) 
    df['X_tp'+str(i)] = (df['X'].shift(i) - df['X'].shift(i+1))/(df['X'].shift(i))

print(df)
pd.set_option('use_inf_as_null', True)

#df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(axis=1)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

X = df.drop('Y', axis=1)
y = df['Y']


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.40)

X_train = X_train.drop('time', axis=1)
X_train = X_train.drop('X_t1', axis=1)
X_train = X_train.drop('X_t2', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('time', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('X_t1', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('X_t2', axis=1)


sc = MinMaxScaler()

X_train = np.array(df['X'])
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 1)
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)

y_train = np.array(df['Y'])
y_train=y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = sc.fit_transform(y_train)


model_data = TimeseriesGenerator(X_train, y_train, 100, batch_size = 10) 

# Initialising the RNN
model = Sequential() 

# Adding the input layerand the LSTM layer
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(None, 1)))

# Adding the output layer
model.add(Dense(1)) 

# Compiling the RNN
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop') 

# Fitting the RNN to the Training set
model.fit_generator(model_data)

# evaluate the model
#scores = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
#print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))


# Getting the predicted values
predicted = X_test
predicted = sc.transform(predicted)
predicted = predicted.reshape((-1, 1, 1))
y_pred = model.predict(predicted)
y_pred = sc.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

When I plot the prediction as this

```
plt.figure
plt.plot(y_test, color = 'red', label = 'Actual')
plt.plot(y_pred, color = 'blue', label = 'Predicted')
plt.title('Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time [INdex]')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The following plot is what I get.

[image]

However, if we plot each column separately,

```
groups = [1, 2]
i = 1
# plot each column
plt.figure()
for group in groups:
    plt.subplot(len(groups), 1, i)
    plt.plot(values[:, group])
    plt.title(df.columns[group], y=0.5, loc='right')
    i += 1
plt.show()
```

The following plots are what we get.

[image]

How can we improve the prediction accuracy?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're doing, but I don't know anything about pandas and its commands. What exactly is your input and output? Do you want the output to be X (as stated) or Y (as in code?). Are you predicting one var based on the other? Or are you predicting the future as well?

Comment: If you're predicting X, shouldn't you be comparing it with X? What is Y exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll let you take it from here, but this should at least get you going.

Note: I see there is some confusion around what variable you are predicting. For this I was predicting the 'Y' which is usually standard. If that's incorrect, just swap the order prior to putting into the create_sequences function. The code should still work, and this is just a starting point for you anyways, you'll need to play around with it quite a bit more to get a good performing network.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(7)

df = pd.read_csv('test32_C_data.csv')
n_features = 100


def create_sequences(data, window=14, step=1, prediction_distance=14):
    x = []
    y = []

    for i in range(0, len(data) - window - prediction_distance, step):
        x.append(data[i:i + window])
        y.append(data[i + window + prediction_distance][0])

    x, y = np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)

    return x, y


# Scaling prior to splitting
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0.01, 0.99))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(df.loc[:, ["Y", "X"]].values)

# Build sequences
x_sequence, y_sequence = create_sequences(scaled_data)

# Create test/train split
test_len = int(len(x_sequence) * 0.15)
valid_len = int(len(x_sequence) * 0.15)
train_end = len(x_sequence) - (test_len + valid_len)
x_train, y_train = x_sequence[:train_end], y_sequence[:train_end]
x_valid, y_valid = x_sequence[train_end:train_end + valid_len], y_sequence[train_end:train_end + valid_len]
x_test, y_test = x_sequence[train_end + valid_len:], y_sequence[train_end + valid_len:]

# Initialising the RNN
model = Sequential()

# Adding the input layerand the LSTM layer
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(14, 2)))

# Adding the output layer
model.add(Dense(1))

# Compiling the RNN
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')

# Fitting the RNN to the Training set
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

# Getting the predicted values
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

# Plot results
pd.DataFrame({"y_test": y_test, "y_pred": np.squeeze(y_pred)}).plot()
```

Differences:

- Using custom sequence generator, 14 step window, 14 step "look-forward" for prediction
- Custom train/test/valid split, you can use the validation set when training for early stopping
- Changed the input shape to include 2 features with a window of 14 input_shape=(14,2)
- 5 epochs

[image: Prediction Result]

Comment: To get it back to the original value, just use the scaler to `inverse_transform`, then it will plot the Y between 0-350. You may need to scale them separately for that as well to keep the proper range for the target variable. As for the output, you can try many different things but this isn't something I can do for you as it requires trial-and-error. Hope this was helpful to get you started at least.

Comment: Correct. As for your `broadcast shape` error. If your output shape is (1694,2) for predicted then I'm confused as that would require you to change the shape of the network. Otherwise, you are likely accidentally passing the x data, not the y. I'd recommend using the standard `x` for independent, and `y` for dependent to avoid future confusion.

Comment: y_test is the actual, and y_pred is the predicted.

Comment: Chris, why is that you are working with `X` as input and `X` as output in the `create sequences` function? Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: The x input is the data that the sequences are generated from. Think of it as a sliding window, capturing multiple values of X for each Y that will be predicted. So you input X values without a window, and the output is a window of X values representing the X values leading up to Y value that's being predicted.